# Show that $a^n-b^n$ has a prime factor which does not divide $a-b$ for all $n>1$ .

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I was asked to prove the following using the **lifting the exponent lemma**.

> Show that $a^n-b^n$ has a prime factor which does not divide $a-b$ for all  $n>1$ .

Using the first lemma, what I got was this:
 if $p$ is any prime greater than $2$,
then we have

> $V_p(a^n-b^n)= V_p(a-b) + V_p(n)$

where $V_p(x)$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$ and $p|a-b$ but does not divide a or b.
I don't know how to approach this and would welcome some hints.

Comment: See this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757819/how-prove-this-an-bn-always-have-prime-factor-p-and-pn).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks. i am trying what i can but the post helped.

Comment: Following the pattern; $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\text{,  }  a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\text{,  } a^4-b^4=(a - b)(a + b)(a^2 + b^2)$, etc. we need to show that some sum of any combination of powers of  $a \text{ and } b$ is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}=\sum_{k=1}^n a^{k-1}b^{n-k}>n\ge\prod_{p|(a-b)} p^{V_p(n)}.
$$

> $$\implies a^n-b^n>\prod_{p|(a-b)} p^{V_p(a^n-b^n)}$$